# Powertip Link to open Sharepoint 2013 Modal Dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint

I created a link that loads a powertip tooltip with a link in it, then i have a jquery function that looks for the class of that link and then opens the content in a modal dialog in sharepoint. Now this works with the links already in the page, but does not work with the link that is in the tooltip.

How can i get to fix this?

This is the code for the powertip tooltip.

```
$(function() {
  var mouseOnDiv = $('.linkclass');
  var tipContent = $('<a href="#" class="modal-link">Text</a>'
  );
  mouseOnDiv.data('powertipjq', tipContent);
  mouseOnDiv.powerTip({
    placement: 's',
    mouseOnToPopup: true
  });
});
```

Here is the code for the modal dialog to load.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
        $("a.modal-link").on("click", function(e){

            var destination = $(this).attr("href"); 

            if(destination.indexOf("?") > -1) {
                destination += "&IsDlg=1";
            }
            else {
                destination += "?IsDlg=1";
            }

            var title = $(this).text(); 
            var dialog = SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog({
                        title: title,
                        url: destination,
                        autoSize: true,
                        width: 1024,
                        height: 800
                    });
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
```